# which mode is to be set on live the website after development in magento?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.2

which mode is to be set on live the website after development in magento..? I'm a newbie to magento, I had read about modes on magento docs website. but i'm not still clear with it.  Anyone tell about this briefly guys.

Comment: Sure that it’s production mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You should enable production mode on live environment.**

Here are the brief description of Magento 2 modes.

> **Default Mode**

Magento 2’s “out-of-the-box” mode. **When you initially launch a Magento 2** site it is typically in Default mode. This mode is a `hybrid of Developer and Production` and appears to be intended to ramp up the time-to-launch for base Magento 2 sites due to the ability to develop without compiling code as well as a standardized set of configurations. While this can lead to a quicker time-to-launch, new modifications and maintenance will ultimately save you time in Developer mode due to the more advanced development functionality outlined in the next section.

In Default mode **errors are logged at the server level** so while debugging is possible, it is not ideal for development.

For each requested file on the site a `symlink is created in the pub/static directory`. This means that in Default mode full page cache is not being fully utilized as the site still serves content dynamically for each request rather than drawing from the cache.

**It is important to note that once a Magento 2 site is switched out of Default mode it is impossible to go back to this mode.** This is because Default mode was not intended long-termterm use, `it was introduced to help launch sites but not to maintain and grow stores moving forward.`

> **Developer Mode**

**The mode in which all development should* be done.** This mode is much slower on the frontend and within the site admin, with the tradeoff that it `automatically compiles code and offers more advanced logging and debugging capabilities than Default or Production modes.` Caching can be utilized while in developer mode it is typically disabled to speed up development testing. This in combination with the lack of a populated and utilized /pub folder leads to exceptionally slow load times.

The tradeoff for the load times comes in the substantially more comprehensive logging and debugging capabilities Default mode offers which include:

Exceptions appear in the error handler rather than being logged, meaning `the actual errors are displayed in the browser rather than displaying just the error number which then has to be tracked down in the file reports at the server.`

`Exceptions are also thrown in the browser when event subscribers cannot be invoked which leads to faster debugging of extension conflicts.`

> **Production Mode**

**All live Magento 2 sites should be in Production mode.** This mode utilizes full page caching alongside a fully built pub folder to pull from, and is optimized `to run smoothly and efficiently leading to the greatest customer experience.` **Debugging is more difficult in Production mode as they are logged at the server level and not displayed to the user on the frontend.**

Anytime you switch from Developer to Production mode **two actions must first be taken:**

`1. Static Deploy`- this populates everything in the pub/static folder which a Production M2 site will then build and serve content from.

`2. Compilation` - this takes your site’s code and merges it into bytecode which ultimately allows for faster retrieval of classes and results in faster page load times on the frontend.
**Production mode is more secure than Default or Developer mode as well due to the fact that there is no symlink created for the pub/static folder.** This means if a malicious user were to gain access to pub/static and make changes they would only be changing duplicate versions of those files which would be overwritten during the next static deploy.

Source: [customerparadigm](https://www.customerparadigm.com)